# Best way to run scheduled code on AWS

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What would be the best way to run a python script on the first of every month?

My situation is I want some data sent to a HipChat room, using the python api, on the first of every month from AWS. The data I want sent is in a text file in a S3 bucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script can execute in under 5 minutes you could do this by creating a [Python Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model.html) function and running it monthly via [Lambda scheduled tasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html). Running this once a month would stay well within the free Lambda usage limits, so your costs would be almost nothing.

If your script takes longer than 5 minutes to execute then you would probably need to schedule this as a cron job on an EC2 instance.

Comment: Would, I be able use pip install stuff? Such as import hipchat

Comment: Yes, you would run that locally, then zip all that up in the deployment package you upload to Lambda. This is documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a Lambda function and use cloudWatch ==> Events ==> Rules and configure it

using:
1:AWS built in timers
2:Cron Expressions

In your case cron is better option